# How to perform a webform_submission query with a conditional based on a custom field in the submission data

Tags: 8, entities, webforms

I'm attempting to query all webforms with a specific id, and sorted by a boolean field that was added to a webform by me in the webform configuration manager. 
Below is my attempt

```
    $submission_ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('webform_submission')
        ->condition('webform_id', $webform_id)
        ->exists('paid')
        ->sort('paid', 'desc')
        ->sort('created', 'desc')
        ->pager(50)
        ->execute();
```

However when I perform this query I get

> Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryException: 'paid' not found in
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\Sql\Tables->ensureEntityTable() (line 316 of
>   core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Query/Sql/Tables.php).

If I omit the ->sort('paid','desc'), but keep the ->sort('created', 'desc') the query works fine. I'm assuming this is because created is one of the base fields defined in the webform entity.

I also tried using 'field.paid', and 'data.paid' as a guess but I ended up with

> Call to a member function getColumns() on boolean in /var/www/aaep.org/http/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Query/Sql/Tables.php
>   on line 228

Is there a way to sort webform submissions by user defined fields in an entity query?

Comment: Webform submission data is not stored using Field API.  Entity queries using element names won't work.  You will need to write a custom database query or try using the Webform Views Integration module. 
 (https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_views)

The webform_query_alter() hook includes some code that shows how to join the 'webform_submission_data' table for custom sorts and conditions.
 (http://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/webform.module#n1126)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to select the Submission IDs (SIDs) from the table webform_submission_data:

```
$select = \Drupal::service('database')
  ->select('webform_submission_data', 'wsd')
  ->fields('wsd', array('sid'))
  ->orderBy('wsd.sid', 'DESC')
  ->condition('wsd.webform_id', $webform_id, '=')
  ->condition('wsd.name', 'paid', '=')
  ->condition('wsd.value', 1, '=')// Not sure how your BOOL value is saved
  ->execute();

// Get all the results.
$results = $select->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Then you need to use entity_load_multiple() or similar to load the entities:

```
if (count($results) >= 1) {
  $submissions = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('webform_submission')
    ->loadMultiple($results);

  foreach ($submissions as $submission) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

Drupal.org thread [Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2858727#comment-12236979) for basis of my answer.